# run php function when order complete

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

I'm new to magento and i don't have any idea about how I can run specific PHP function when user order completion.
can anyone explain me how I can do this?
I read about `event/observer` but I don't understand how to use
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "observer" is a fancy name for a method on a class definition that is executed on an event. Any number of observers can be fired for any one event.

To create one you first create a module. In the module `config.xml` definition locate (or create) the `<global>`, `<frontend>` and `<adminhtml>` nodes. You can create the event listener in any one of those 3 nodes. To register it, do the following:

```
<events>
    <event_name_here>
        <observers>
            <store>
                <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                <method>methodName</method>
            </store>
        </observers>
    </event_name_here>
</events>
```

To get a list of [valid event names you can visit this site here](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/).

In your module, create a class file called `Observer.php` in the `Model` directory. It will look something like:

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function methodName($observer)
    {
        //observer data is in $observer->getEvent()
    }
}
```

From there, whenever the event name you're listening to is called, your module's Observer model will be loaded and the method you've registered will fire.

Comment: Thanks, I do what you told but nothing will happen, I was observe event `customer_login` and place `die;` on method but nothing will happen, I placed `<events>` in `<frontend>`

Comment: I found where I missed up, thank you very much, but what event should observe for order completion?

Comment: `sales_order_place_after` is always a good bet - but be careful; exceptions raised in this event may prevent order entry.

Comment: thank you very much, can you please place event name in your answer, for other who has same question @philwinkle